# Composition of functions of given set

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

If   ∀x ∈ {1,2,3,4} , $f$(x) = $ x^2 $ and  ∀x ∈ {2,4,3,6} , $g$(x) = $ x+1 $.
Find $ (g\; o\; f ), (f\; o\; g)\; and \;Im(f \;o \;g)$

I dont understand the question much. If someone can help me it would be really helpful.

$ (g\; o\; f ) (x)$ = $g(f(x)) = x^2 + 1$

$ (f\; o\; g ) $ = $f(g(x)) = (x+1)^2$ 
Is this what they are expecting as an answer or is there more for it?

Comment: For both compositions, I think you have to check that the result of the inner function is in the domain of the outer function, e. g. $f(g(6))$ is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas are correct. However, maybe the question is also asking to find the domains and ranges. For example, note that $(f \;o \;g)(6)$ is simply undefined because $g(6)=7$ is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: So if we consider $(fog)(3) then f(g(3)) = f(4)$ we say its defined?

Comment: $(f\circ g)(3)$ is defined, yes.